# How to check if any files are open in a directory?

Tags: c++, file-io, operating-system

I am trying to delete all files in a folder, but if a file is left open, it will not delete. I need to check the folder for any open files, write their names to a text document, and then close the open files. As I don't have much experience, I am first trying to check one file in the same folder, then all in the same folder, then all in a different folder. I don't want to be to needy or demanding, so just some help with the first step would be nice.

I don't have a ton of experience coding, but I have tried using fstream and (name.is_open). I may be using them wrong, so I have not yet ruled them out.

```
// ifstream::is_open
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

void checkFiles() {
int done = 0;
while(done != 1){
    std::cout << "Enter 0 for continue or 1 for done: ";
    std::cin >> done;

    std::ifstream ifs ("test.txt");

    if (ifs.is_open()) {
        // Print that file is open, then close
        std::cout << "File is open\n";
        std::ifstream.close():
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "File not open\n";
    }
}
```

For this bit of code, if the file is open, it should say "File is open."
If not, it should say "File not open"

Even if I force quit the .txt file, it still says that it is open.

Eventually, I want to have a new file that displays what files were open, as well as closing all the open files.

Comment: "if a file is left open, it will not delete" - On Windows, no. On Unix, yes it will.

Comment: What do you mean by "open file"? Open by your application or by any application?

Comment: (a) What happens when you try to delete a file that is open is system-dependent, and you have not told us what system you are targeting. Some systems will not delete the file. Some will (at least in effect) mark it for deletion, and it will be deleted when closed. (b) The design is faulty: You are attempting to know whether a delete will fail because a file is open when the delete is attempted, but you are asking whether a file is open **now**, before you try the delete. Closed files may be opened, and open files may be closed between your test and the delete.

Comment: A better design is to attempt to delete each file and, if the delete fails, handle that by writing the file’s name to the text document and/or performing whatever other action you want.

Comment: Do you mean file opened by your program or opened in general (in an editor, in use by another program)?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Not necessarily. An operating system could theoretically expose the functionality of deleting all files in a directory at once.

Comment: @Valentino Opened in general

Comment: @LiorKogan Any application

Comment: @Jackson148: `while (done == 1)` would immediately fail... I edited your code, hopefully to say what you meant.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I forgot to mention that I am working on Windows, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @einpoklum Thank you, that is what I meant to do, just wrote it the wrong way.

Comment: @einpoklum: That is not relevant to the problem asked about. For any problem, one could speculate on a magical solution in the form of some system call that made all other programming irrelevant. That is not helpful to analyzing the practical case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Standard C++ offers us the [filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) to handle files and directories (standardized in C++17). However, checking which files are open is not - as far as I can tell - a feature of that library.

The `is_open()` method for `std::fstream`'s is something completely different than what you're trying to check for: It tells you whether the particular stream object is in an open state (which would mean association with an open file) - and it doesn't use the OS to check which files are open. Typically, it's just a way to check whether you've closed it someplace else in your own program; at most, it might ensure that the OS has not unilaterally closed the OS-side file access handle. So, you won't get anywhere in that direction.

I also believe, though I'm not 100% certain, that Boost doesn't have a library which offers this capability, either. [Boost's `filesystem` library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/filesystem/) is almost identical to `std::filesystem`, as the latter was based on it.

So, to the best of my knowledge, you either need to directly use operating-system-specific calls to do this, or look for a library offering this functionality, elsewhere.

If you haven't found anything else, you could track how this is currently done with what's available in userspace. There's a utility called [`lsof`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof). It's available on some operating systems based on Linux, Darwin, FreeBSD and Solaris  (e.g. available on MacOS). It's maintained [here](https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof). The source code seems to be rather atrocious C. An intrepid developer could parse that mess, figure out what it does, extract the parts relevant for your specific use case, and refactor it into a reasonable, readable and short(ish) C++ function. I realize you (OP) might not be up for it at this point, but - maybe someone else reading this answer will get inspired to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The `pfiles` command shows the open files for a process. You can run it for all or some processes.

However, Solaris (and UNIX) in general allows you to delete open files.  The file can still be read and written while it is open (but deleted), but nobody else can open the same file and the file will be deleted when all processes have the file closed.